# Second select query not running after a PIVOT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot

So basically I have a code similar to this one **to do a Stored Procedure**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [TempTable]

SELECT [Item1], [Item2], [Item3] 
INTO [TempTable]
FROM [Table1] K 
INNER JOIN [Table2] C
WHERE [Item3] = @timeVariable
GROUP BY [Item1];

SELECT [Item1], [Item2], [Item3], [Item2]/[Item3] AS Sum1
FROM [TempTable];
GO
```

The thing is that when I'm trying to run the second query it shows an error in the columns.

It doesn't happen if I run the code separately.

For example:

1. Running first the upper part

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [TempTable]

SELECT [Item1], [Item2], [Item3] 
INTO [TempTable]
FROM [Table1] K 
INNER JOIN [Table2] C
WHERE [Item3] = @timeVariable
GROUP BY [Item1];
```

2. Then the whole code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [TempTable]

SELECT [Item1], [Item2], [Item3] 
INTO [TempTable]
FROM [Table1] K 
INNER JOIN [Table2] C
WHERE [Item3] = @timeVariable
GROUP BY [Item1];

SELECT [Item1], [Item2], [Item3], [Item2]/[Item3] AS Sum1
FROM [TempTable];
GO
```

I'm trying to find a way to run the whole query successfully without getting an error in the first run in the second query and having to run the query separately.

The error is

> Invalid column name 'columnname'

Comment: Try putting `go` between the two queries so they are not in the same batch.

Comment: It doesn't show an error now!
The only thing is that due to being a stored procedure now it runs only the first part!
I'll do an edit clarifying that detail! Thank you!

Comment: Why are you dropping and recreating anyway?

Comment: Because this table is used in other stored procedures to transport the data as well!
So I can make operations in another query that for example the columns in a pivot will not let me!

Answer (score 0):

```
You have use **GROUP BY [Item1]**
Group by user for aggregate like Sum, Avg, Count etc.
If you use Group by then your code should be like below:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [TempTable]

SELECT [Item1], SUM([Item2])[Item2], SUM([Item3])Item3
INTO [TempTable]
FROM [Table1] K 
INNER JOIN [Table2] C ON K.[Join Column] = C.[Join Column]
WHERE [Item3] = @timeVariable
GROUP BY [Item1];

SELECT [Item1], [Item2], [Item3], [Item2]/[Item3] AS Sum1
FROM [TempTable]; 
GO

//Here Join Column would be your primary key and foreign key
```